# React app shows directory files during `yarn build`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg, serve

My React app is currently being served on a server by first building the React app, then using `serve` to serve the files.

```
cd path/to/reactapp
yarn build
serve -s build/ -l 80
```

However, when I do a `git pull` to get updates and then rebuild using `yarn build` command, going to the website URL will show a page of files.

[image]

What is the correct way to update/rebuild the React app and still avoid temporarily showing the page of files?

Comment: Have you tried adding `"homepage": "."` to package.json? Did you already solve the problem, how?